# Add "Sort by Featured" in woocommerce search results

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

in woocommerce, in the product loop after a search, how can I show featured products before the others prducts?

I tried:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'sport_catalog_orderby' );
function sport_catalog_orderby( $orderby ) {
    $orderby['featured'] = __('Featured', 'woocommerce');

    return $orderby;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'sport_product_query' );
function sport_product_query( $q ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && isset($_GET['orderby']) && 'featured' === esc_attr($_GET['orderby']) ) {
        $tax_query = $q->get('tax_query');
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'featured',
        );
        $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
        $q->set( 'order', 'DESC' ); // Or "ASC"
    }
}
```

But only featured products are displayed. I need tho show also non-featured after them.
So I tried:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'sport_catalog_orderby' );
function sport_catalog_orderby( $orderby ) {
    // Add a new sorting option called "Featured" to the dropdown
    $orderby['featured'] = __('Featured', 'woocommerce');
    
    // Return the modified sorting options
    return $orderby;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'sport_product_query' );
function sport_product_query( $q ) {
    // Check if not in admin panel and if the orderby parameter is set to "featured"
    if ( ! is_admin() && isset($_GET['orderby']) && 'featured' === esc_attr($_GET['orderby']) ) {
        // Set the meta query to order by featured products first, then non-featured
        $q->set( 'meta_query', array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => '_featured',
                'value'   => 'yes',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => '_featured',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
        ));
        
        // Set the order as DESC (or ASC if needed)
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $q->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
```

The last code shows both featured and non featured but some featured is "mixed" in the non featured products.